# Is there a word that means 'deliberately ignorant, choosing to ignore the facts'?

Tags: adjectives, confusables

I know what this word really means but I cannot help to think that ignorant also means he ignores his surrounding or the consequences of his actions. "He was ignorant, unwilling to warn the police about what has been happening next door for years” for example.
Can anyone tell me the word I am looking for? Or is it too broad to find a suitable adjective?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I don't know about a single word, but what you're describing sounds like ***willful ignorance*** or ***willful blindness***, described by [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/willful_ignorance) as

> A decision in bad faith to avoid becoming informed about something so
>   as to avoid having to make undesirable decisions that such information
>   might prompt

Comment: [Rational Wiki](http://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Willful_ignorance) has a good article.

Comment: While it seems an established term in Law, the modifier *willful* does not seem justified in general English usage: people have a tendency to turn a blind eye to what is not strictly in conformity with their beliefs. See also: "Willful ignorance is the state and practice of ignoring any sensory input that appears to contradict one’s inner model of reality. At heart, it is almost certainly driven by confirmation bias." at **RationalWiki** http://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Willful_ignorance

Comment: "Willful ignorance" is a phrase I hear commonly to mean exactly this, but I've never heard "willful blindness."

Comment: "Feign oblivion" could also be used in this case.

Answer (score 8):

An expression of the *ostrich effect* is *[bury one's head in the sand](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bury+head+in+the+sand)*,  *hide one's head in the sand*; *have one's head in the sand*:

> Fig. to ignore or hide from obvious signs of danger.

.

Answer (score 5):

In this particular case the phrase *[in denial](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/denial)* seems appropriate:

> in a state of refusing to believe something that is true.
>
> *Mary was in **denial** about her illness and refused treatment.*

Answer (score 3):

Obstinate - perversely adhering to an opinion, purpose, or course in spite of reason, arguments, or persuasion .

Answer (score 2):

You could say he's got a [***three wise monkeys*** attitude](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22three%20wise%20monkeys%20attitude%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) *(speak, see, hear no evil)*...

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[To ignore](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ignore)  can conveys the concept of being *deliberatly ignorant or choosing to ignore*.

> - To refuse to pay attention to; disregard.
> - to refrain from noticing or recognizing: *to ignore insulting remarks.*

- he simply ignored what had been happening next door for years.

(TFD)

Answer (score 2):

Ignorant is used or taken offensively, but I personally feel it means that they do not know something (Unaware) and I would never use that word as a replacement for 'uneducated'. Like blissful ignorance: He was blissfully ignorant that a gang of thieves were waiting around the corner.

Anyway, with that in mind, the word I think you might be looking for is  **"Disingenuous"**  which means to pretend you don't know something... probably in an attempt to gain an advantage.

e.g. *The disingenuous politician hid important facts from the voters.*

or maybe like so *"No, errm, I have no idea. You'd be better off asking someone else", he said disingenuously as he dashed towards the beautiful yet clueless blonde customer at the end of the aisle.*

Answer (score 1):

This is a *[cognitive bias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cognitive_biases)*

> tendencies to think in certain ways that can lead to systematic
>   deviations from a standard of rationality or good judgment, and are
>   often studied in psychology and behavioral economics.

When a person "deliberately" ignores negative information it is called an *[optimism bias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimism_bias)* or the *[ostrich effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostrich_effect)*.

When a person "deliberately" ignores positive information it is called *[pessimism bias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pessimism_bias)*.

Answer (score 1):

The term to use in my opinion depends upon the reason for adopting an attitude of ***willful-neglect***.

If the person is turning a blind eye out of fear or weakness, a good term might be ***cowardous***, if the person is simply doesn't want to get involved because it would be too much trouble, a good term might be ***selfish***, if the person doesn't want their world-view altered by truly considering reality, an appropriate term would be ***denial*** or ***dellusional***, if the person is simply de-prioritizing or self-justifying the the effects of their behavior / actions on others, I would suggest something like ***irresponsible***, ***psychopathic*** or ***sociopathic***, perhaps qualified to indicate the depths of their attitude (e.g. ***mildly psychopathic***), if the person is simply unable to assess the impact of the current situation, a term such as ***socially impared*** or even ***stupid*** might be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

#### A particularly British term for this would be *“Looked the other way”*.

**Definition:**

> **Look the other way** - Deliberately ignore wrongdoing by others. *(Source: [Google](http://gog.is/define+look+the+other+way))*

---

**In a Sentence:**

> “He ***looked the other way*** for years, blissfully ignorant of the illicit goings on next door.”

Comment: I don't think that's particularly British ... Americans use it, too.

Comment: @Peter it sounds to me like it would've originated from cockneys but that's purely a gut feeling with no evidence to back it. I have no way of verifying whether it's common in America though.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been long, but everyone here seemingly forgot ["turn a deaf ear"](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/turn+a+deaf+ear). It does contain context of *deliberate ignorance*.

And it is mostly different from "turning a blind eye", with latter mostly used when "witnessing something happening/happened" is in context.

Answer (score 0):

**blinder-wearer**

> Editor & Publisher - Volume 118, Part 1 - Page 45 1985
>
> No doubt this **blinder-wearer** also sees a distinction between the
>   images displayed on his television screen.

Comment: Does a blind-wearer do so deliberately?

Comment: 'Might' may not do for OP. :)

Comment: He needs to know how to use it and couch it. This is just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

***[Apathetic](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/apathetic)***?

> having or showing little or no emotion; indifferent

Also, ***[negligent](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/negligent?showCookiePolicy=true)***, perhaps?

> habitually neglecting duties, responsibilities, etc; lacking attention, care, or concern; neglectful

Answer (score 0):

Obdurate - stubbornly refusing to change one's opinion or course of action.

Comment: This doesn't have the necessary 'turn a blind eye to' meaning OP asks for.

Comment: Welcome to ELU, Mike! Please, provide an authoritative link for definitions and other references: [obdurate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/obdurate) ODO. One man's opinion, does not a definition make.

Answer (score 0):

"She deliberately *ignored* the stench of sweat and urine of the homeless, and treated them as she would any other human beings."

There are many ways of expressing wilful ignorance in a pejorative sense, as you may see in the answers given here, but deliberate ignorance in and of itself is not inherently negative.

You may simply describe actions rather than apply an adjective that is loaded with judgement or even medical diagnosis.

"Mungo feigned ignorance of the fact that his neighbor was the civil-rights activist being sought by the secret police to be tortured and murdered."

Would you say that any of the following apply to Mungo?

tactical stupidity
lame
Passive-aggressive
wilful ignorance
wilful blindness
bury one's head in the sand
in denial
three wise monkeys attitude
cognitive bias
optimism bias
ostrich effect
obstinate
apathetic 
negligent
blinder-wearer
wilful neglect
cowardice
selfish
delusional
irresponsible
psychopathic
sociopathic
socially impaired
obdurate

Answer (score 0):

One of the definitions for obtuse is "annoyingly insensitive or slow to understand". It is often used in a phrase "deliberately obtuse".

Answer (score 0):

negligent

1. habitually neglecting duties, responsibilities, etc; lacking attention, care, or concern; neglectful
2. careless or nonchalant

Synonyms:  negligent, derelict, lax, neglectful, remiss, slack
These adjectives mean guilty of a lack of due care or concern: The negligent landlord failed to repair the window. By not voting, he was derelict in his civic duty. If you're lax in attending class, your grades will suffer. Many neighbors felt that he had been neglectful of his property. It was remiss of her not to call to tell us she was coming. The teacher was slack in maintaining discipline.

Source (http://www.thefreedictionary.com)

Comment: If you quote (let's say from AHDEL), there's a legal (never mind an ELU) requirement to acknowledge the source.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Source added

Comment: Neglect does not imply *deliberately ignorant* or *choosing to ignore*. Neglect is often an unconscious filtering.

Comment: Neglect can be both deliberate and unconscious. I would argue it would depend on the context of the neglect.
It was the closest single word I could think to define the OP.
To make the cause of the neglect clear, I guess the ideal answer would be wilfully neglect, as someone else has suggested.
But was trying to think of a succint one word answer for post.

Answer (score -2):

Why not *oblivious*? It suggests that a person is not paying attention.

Comment: Another answer that does not address the part of the question that has to do with deliberateness, **choosing** to ignore.