# Describing the feeling of being aware of the truth of a situation yet not liking it

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I've been attempting to summarise the emotion of knowing the truth about something and disliking it yet pretending it's not the case and not wanting to ask/clarify it, even though it's in the back of your mind and you're fully aware you're pretending.

I can't seem to phrase it in a simpler manner however this is the best I can describe it with such few words, so I was wondering if there was a less complicated term/word for it that I haven't been able to find.

Apologies for the long question

Comment: What is the object of the dislike (it)? Is it the fact of knowing that particular thing or instead, is it the dislike of the thing itself? This should be made precise, first.

Comment: fatalism or silent lucidity ?

Comment: You might want to add an example sentence to get a precise term for this.

Comment: Closely related: [Is there a word that means deliberately ignorant, choosing to ignore?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/237468/is-there-a-word-that-means-deliberately-ignorant-choosing-to-ignore)

Comment: "to be in denial" https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+in+denial

Answer (score 3):

### [Cognitive dissonance](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cognitive%20dissonance)

> psychological conflict resulting from incongruous beliefs and attitudes held simultaneously

This [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_dissonance) article will tell you all you want to know.

It covers the discomfort of holding the conflicting positions but not necessarily the reluctance to resolve them.

### [In denial](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/denial)

> refusing to admit the truth or reality of something unpleasant

Better covers the unwillingness to confirm the unpalatable truth.

Comment: I believe the truth is acknowledged in the OP's scenario, so your second option is not appropriate. Your first, however, is very apt.

Comment: @Joachim someone who is "in denial" *is* aware of the truth, but suppresses it. Otherwise they would not be in that state. You cannot be in denial of something that you are not aware of. That's the point of this stock expression, which is different from just "denying".

Answer (score 0):

The colloquial phrase that comes to mind is 'to have a sinking feeling' about something.
Example:

> She set out to work hoping to beat the storm, but she had a sinking
> feeling because of the hard rain and rising water levels in the
> street. She eventually gave up and turned back.